# readtable on text file ignores first row which contains the column names

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a tab delimited text file which contains some data organised into columns with the first row acting as column names such as:

```
TN Stim Task RT
1   A    A    500.2
2   B    A    569
3   C    A    654
```

and so on.

I am trying to read this textfile into MATLAB(r2018a) using readtable with

```
Data1 = readtable(filename);
```

I manage to get all the data in `Data1` table, but the column names are showing as `Var1`, `Var2` etc. If I use Name Value pairs to specify to read first row as column names as in:

```
Data1 = readtable(filename, 'ReadVariableNames', true);
```

then I get the column names as the first data row, i.e.

```
1  A  A  500.2
```

So it just looks like it is ignoring the first row completely. How can I modify the `readtable` call to use the entries on the first row as column names?

Comment: it reads fine in r2018b when I test your sample data - so can you add the matlab version.

Comment: r2018a. I will add it to the question as well

Comment: What is the extension for your file name? If it is non-standard, you may have to add `'FileType', 'text'` to your call to `readtable`.

Comment: .txt. Is that non-standard?

Comment: No, that's standard. It loads fine for me in R2016b.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the way your sample file text is formatted above, it appears that the column labels are separated by spaces instead of by tabs the way the data is. In this case, [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) will assume (based on the data) that the [delimiter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#btx_238-1-Delimiter) is a tab and treat the column labels as a [header line to skip](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#btx_238-1-HeaderLines). Add tabs between them and you should be good to go.

Test with spaces between column labels:

```
% File contents:
TN Stim Task RT
1   A   A   500.2
2   B   A   569
3   C   A   654

>> Data1 = readtable('sample_table.txt')

Data1 = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4   % Default names
    ____    ____    ____    _____

    1       'A'     'A'     500.2
    2       'B'     'A'       569
    3       'C'     'A'       654
```

Test with tabs between column labels:

```
% File contents:
TN  Stim    Task    RT
1   A   A   500.2
2   B   A   569
3   C   A   654

>> Data1 = readtable('sample_table.txt')

Data1 = 

    TN    Stim    Task     RT  
    __    ____    ____    _____

    1     'A'     'A'     500.2
    2     'B'     'A'       569
    3     'C'     'A'       654
```

Comment: I formatted the data above with spaces because i couldn't get tabs to work. My data file has tabs, however.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It appears there was an additional tab in some of the rows after the last column. Because of this, `readtable` was reading it as an additional column, but did not have a column name to assign to it. It seems that if any of the column names are missing, it names them all as Var1, Var2, etc.

Comment: It seems weirder than that. What I found: 1) If all the rows (labels and data) have a trailing tab, everything loads fine with an extra column of `NaN` with a default label. 2) If all the data rows have a trailing tab, you get an extra column of `NaN` and *all* the labels are default. 3) If the label row or first row of data has a trailing tab, the labels are all default. 4) If any of the other data rows has a trailing tab, everything looks fine. The moral of the story: format consistency is key!